# Make Laravel Mix Output to Multiple Locations

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to set up a multisite solution, where I need to share assets between different sites. The sites are located in their specific folder, and I have a separate assets folder for building CSS and JS.

I use Laravel Mix for compiling these assets, and I would like to have the output files end up in all site folders.

My setup is like this:

- Assets

  - css
  - js
- Site1

  - dist
- Site2

  - dist

When building the files from assets/css|js, I want the resulting files to end up in both Site1/dist and Site2/dist.

Usually, I would use the `.setPublicPath()` method in Laravel Mix to define the output directory, but that one only takes one path. How can I get multiple output locations working?

Comment: Any chance that you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You can mix all your files then use the mix.copy() function to copy the generated files to the other folders.

mix.js(...)

mix.copy('site1/js', 'site2/js');

[More informations on the official documentation](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/copying-files) :)